# Instantiating hexagons in a circle around an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I am trying to instantiate some hexagons around a central hexagon but I'm getting an odd gap between some of them and I cant figure out what's causing it. The hexagons on the top and bottom should be closer to the white hexagon in the middle. I've read up on this site  [CatLikeCodiing](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/hex-map/part-1/) on how to create hexagonal grids and the math looks right. Any ideas what the issues may be?

[Hex Grid Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEeiH.png)

```
outerRadius = hexButton.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.x;
innerRadius = (Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2) * outerRadius;        

Debug.Log(string.Format("OUTER RADIUS: {0}", outerRadius));
Debug.Log(string.Format("INNER RADIUS: {0}", innerRadius));   

startPos = Instantiate(hexButton, Vector3.zero, hexButton.transform.rotation);
startPos.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("PanelMain").transform, false);
startPos.name = string.Format("Start Hex");
for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
{
     if (i <= 6)
     {
         var temp = Instantiate(hexButton, new Vector3(outerRadius * 2, 0, 0), hexButton.transform.rotation);       
         temp.transform.RotateAround(hexButton.transform.position, Vector3.back, 60 * i);
         temp.transform.rotation = hexButton.transform.rotation;
         temp.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("PanelMain").transform, false);
         temp.GetComponent<Button>().image.color = Color.green;
         temp.name = string.Format("Hex: {0}", i);
     }            

}
```

**FIX**

[Hex Fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vGwn.png)

```
#region 
outerRadius = hexButton.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.y * 0.5f;
innerRadius = (Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2) * outerRadius;
hexWidth = hexButton.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width;
offset = hexWidth * 0.93333333333f;

Debug.Log(string.Format("OUTER RADIUS: {0}", outerRadius));
Debug.Log(string.Format("INNER RADIUS: {0}", innerRadius));
Debug.Log(string.Format("WIDTH: {0}", gap));

startPos = Instantiate(hexButton, Vector3.zero, hexButton.transform.rotation);
startPos.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("PanelMain").transform, false);
startPos.name = string.Format("Start Hex");
for (int i = 0; i < level -1 ; i++)
{
    if (i <= 6)
    {
        var temp = Instantiate(hexButton, new Vector3(offset, 0, 0), hexButton.transform.rotation);       
        temp.transform.RotateAround(hexButton.transform.position, Vector3.back, 60 * i);
        temp.transform.rotation = hexButton.transform.rotation;
        temp.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("PanelMain").transform, false);
        temp.GetComponent<Button>().image.color = Color.green;
        temp.name = string.Format("Hex: {0}", i);
    }            
}
#endregion
```

Comment: I believe your issue is using .rect.x. The tutorial you linked specifies that the outerRadius is the distance from the center to any corner of the hexagon. If you look at the visual shown in the example, if you were to take the width of the image there it would not be this length. A quick and dirty fix is to check the box on your Image component of your prefab Preseve Aspect Ratio to true, then subtract values from your outerRadius until it looks correct.

Comment: Hi user3657449 thanks for pointing that out I updated the code to use the rect.y / 0.5f to get the correct outer radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code would work as expected if your hexagons were symmetrical, meaning that `rect.x == rect.y`. But your hexagons are not symmetrical, your `rect.y` is slightly less that `rect.x`.
The code puts the hexagons along an ideal circle around the center hexagon, and if you imagine a circle with radius `rect.x * 2` and with the center in the center point, you'll see that they are definitely placed correctly.
How to fix what you get here? Well, I would rather write some new code from scratch so it could take into account the hexagons proportions. For instance, the approach of simple rotation with `transform.Rotate()` by 60 degrees each won't work reliably if you won't adjust the angle and/or distance from the center point. It already have some offset, barely noticable with only one level of hexagons, but if you add another 12 hexagons around the green ones and than another 24, the gap between 2 hexagons left and right to each other will get increased more and more. On the image you already can see that there is a little gap between top-left and top-right hexagons (same with bottom-left and bottom-right), while there shouldn't be a gap, just like there's no gap between left, center and right hexagons. Yeah, it is also caused by the proportions not being taken into account.
Basically, to properly place the asymmetrical hexagons like these, you would have to place them along an ellipse instead of a circle.
Sorry for not providing code examples. Maybe all you actually need is just make the hexagons symmetrical and it will be fine already, so there's no point in trying to find a new formula.
However, here is a question about getting a point at ellipse at given angle:  [How to find the point on ellipse given the angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762077/how-to-find-the-point-on-ellipse-given-the-angle/17762156)
You could use that to get a point at the ellipse at 60 degrees to place top-right hex at that position, than find a point at the ellipse at 120 degrees to place the top-left hex, and so on.

Comment: Hi Emriq, Thanks for explaining it so clearly what is actually happening. I remade the hexagon image and made sure it was symmetrical. I also updated the code from the suggestion user3657449 gave about using the rect.y * 0.5f to get the correct outer radius  and its looking a lot better now.